# jquery find() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently I am having a problem with my jquery code. I was trying to get the elements from the html using the jquery find method but its not working. I have tried changing the elements name but still i cant find where is my mistake.

Here is the following html code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class = "dropdown"><a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span>About Us</span><b class = "caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                            <li data-slide = '1'><a href = "#">Philosophy</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Founding Members</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Committee</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Code of Ethics</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide='2'><a href="#">Digital Ecosystem</a></li>
                    <li data-slide='3'><a href="#">Fellow & Members</a></li>
                    <li data-slide='4'><a href="#">SIGs</a></li>
                    <li data-slide='5'><a href="#">Local Chapters</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="7"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="8"><a href="#">Our Service</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onClick="window.open('logout.php','_self','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes, location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, resizable=yes')">
                            <?php 
                            if (isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])) {
                                echo "Log Out";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" onClick="window.open('login.php','_self','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes, location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, resizable=yes')">
                            <?php 
                            if (!isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])) {
                                echo "Login/Register";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

I have included my jquery code too :

```
 var links = $('.nav, .navbar-nav, .navbar-right').find('li');
```

Actually what the code does is once it find the 'li' html elements it slides the page each time a 'li' element is being clicked. Now if I click on the 'li' elements my page doesnt scrolls to the selected page. it would be great if someone is there to solve my problem.

Comment: This probably won't make a difference, but `.nav, .navbar-nav, .navbar-right` "selects" the same element three times. If you want to get the `.nav` element that also has the classes `navbar-nav` and `navbar-right`, you have to concatenate the class names: `.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right`. Read the jQuery documentation before you use a selector: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/.

Comment: At the top you say that `.find()` doesn't work, but at the bottom you say it finds the `li` elements, and you describe a different sounding issue. What's the actual problem?

Comment: @FelixKling -  Should it be .nav , .navbar-nav , .navbar-right instead of .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right

Comment: @cookiemonster actually it should find the 'li' elements but now since it cant find the 'li' elements.. the function is not working.

Comment: So you're saying it *should* find them but it never does? If so, we don't have enough information in your question to know the problem. There's nothing wrong with the code you provided, other than the oddity that @FelixKling pointed out, which shouldn't really break anything.

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev: Are you asking a question? No, it should not be `.nav, .navbar-nav, .navbar-right`, as I explained in my comment.

Comment: @cookiemonster i guess its better i provide the codes in a jsfiddle

Comment: So your question is how to find li elements inside a ul by classes?

Comment: @FelixKling i have tried putting a comma in it but still its not working...

Comment: @raaj5671: Nope, narrow the code down to the minimum amount that still reproduces the issue, and post it here.

Comment: @raaj5671: By the way, how are you testing to see if it found the `li` elements? Is it only by the expected page behavior, or are you logging the `.length` of the result?

Comment: *"i have tried putting a comma in it but still its not working"* I think you haven't understood my comment. You are *currently* using a selector with commas, but you shouldn't. Either way, it doesn't relate to your problem, it's just odd.

Comment: @cookiemonster [link](http://pastebin.com/1j2W6uZR) actually this is the whole main.js function which it should do. But what i have done is i have removed the 'navigation' and change it to 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

Comment: Lots of global variables you're creating there. What is `.stellar()` and `.waypoint`? Have you done any debugging using `console.log()`?

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: @FelixKling: That should be an automated comment applied to all JavaScript questions. :)

Comment: @cookiemonster stellar() and waypoint() is the .js files actually

Comment: @FelixKling i tried to debug the code but i cant find any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if you really want the "links" tags):

```
var links = $('.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right').find('a');
```

Comment: I have tried its not working. maybe you can take a look at the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XgX5m/)